# Why do we need a service in android? Music play can be done by background thread also

Tags: android, service

I was asked this question in an interview. I am not sure if this the right forum to ask this question because it does not involve any code, but an understanding of android concept.

The question is 'Why do we need a service when everything can be done by a background thread in Android?'
Service runs in the main thread, why do we need something that runs in the main thread but in the background? 
Examples like music play can be done in the background thread also so why do we need a service.

Please let me know if this should be asked in another forum.

Comment: usually if we want a running job even if the user is not interacting with the app, we use service, in your example we start a new thread inside the service and don't hog the main thread and set the service priority to foreground(so that system knows that the user is continuously aware of the service) we also attach status bar notification so that the service can directly listen to events even if application is in background

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

**Service:**
Service is like Activity. but it doesn't require UI to work with. whereas when the thread created from the activity , thread will run until the activity lives. so, if you play the music in thread it will run. but it will crash when the activity ends, whereas when you implemented the music playing from service it will run entire the life cycle of the service.

See my answer [boundservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540312/how-to-make-sure-service-is-not-killed/41540930#41540930) to communicate between service and activity. when your music player runs you have to maintain the notification on notification panel.

**UPDATE**

When you are playing the music with background thread, the music will play even the app closed your background thread will become orphanage thread. You cannot control the state of the music player. Whereas when you are working with service ,music will play and it won't become orphanage service when the app exits. When you recreat the app you can communicate with music player whereas background thread cannot.

Comment: Notification can be maintained by activity also. And music can be played by a background thread. The question is why do we need a service.

Comment: What do you mean @zeekHuge

Comment: @Noorul : my bad ! bound-services support inter-PROCESS communication.

Comment: Service is an Android wrapper around active resources. You can of course play music from a background thread in your Activity or even your Application, but unless you have an Activity or Service in foreground your app process can be killed at any time. And so dies your music.