# how to send data from background service to activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, background-service

i try almost code in the internet, but i can't solve it.
i want to send data from specific method in the service to activity.
i use intent(putExtra), but it doesn't go to activity class.

here is my RecoBackgroundRangingService.java
(i omit unnecessary code)

```
private static final String TAG = "RecoBackgroundRangingService";
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.hello ";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
int counter = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
Log.i("BackRangingService", "onCreate()");
super.onCreate();

intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"on create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void didEnterRegion(RECOBeaconRegion region, Collection<RECOBeacon> beacons) {
/**
 * For the first run, this callback method will not be called.
 * Please check the state of the region using didDetermineStateForRegion() callback method.
 *

//Get the region and found beacon list in the entered region
    Log.i("BackRangingService", "didEnterRegion() - " + region.getUniqueIdentifier());
    this.popupNotification("Inside of " + region.getUniqueIdentifier());
//Write the code when the device is enter the region

     DisplayLoggingInfo();

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"did enter region", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//this.startRangingWithRegion(region); //start ranging to get beacons inside of the region
//from now, stop ranging after 10 seconds if the device is not exited
}

private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
//Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

//intent.putExtra("time", new Date().toLocaleString());
//intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));

    intent.putExtra("status", 1);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"display logging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

here is my CheckActivity.java
(when i receive data, my purpose is that store data to the server. therefore, i don't need to use layout. So, in order to check data, i use toast "hello". but toast never popup my phone...)

```
public class CheckActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "CheckActivity";
    private Intent intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);

        intent = new Intent(this, RecoBackgroundRangingService.class);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "check activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUI(intent);
    }
};


@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(RecoBackgroundRangingService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);
    }


    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {

        int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", -1);


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to try EventBus library: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: you need to use bound service.

Comment: check this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117812/why-do-we-a-service-in-android-music-play-can-be-done-by-background-thread-also/43118076#43118076

Comment: putExtra doesn't work from background service, if you want to access activity class from your background service you have to call a local broadcastmanager, but it only works if activity is on active mode in an application

Comment: EventBus is the best way for making a communication bridge between activity and service.

Comment: btw, you know that you have registered the broadcast listener inside `onResume()` . right ?  so you will have to pause your app (by pressing home key ?) and then resume it back, so that `onResume()` is actually invoked to get the broadcast listener registered.

Comment: @ZeekHuge your comment is wrong. `onResume()` gets called when the `Activity` is shown on the display. When the `Activity` is started, `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are all called. This code will get executed every time the `Activity` is displayed on screen.

Comment: @ShashwatGupta your comment is wrong. Of course you can call `putExtra()` to add data to a broadcast `Intent` that is then broadcast by a `Service` and received by a registered listener in an `Activity`. That is a standard behaviour to communicate between services and activities.

Comment: Is `DisplayLoggingInfo()` being called? Are you sure?

Comment: @DavidWasser : Oh ! I see it [there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) . Thanks to correct me.

Comment: @Noorul It isn't necessary to use a bound `Service` to send data from a `Service` to an `Activity`. Sending data in a broadcast `Intent` from the `Service` to the `Activity` is a perfectly valid and simple way to communicate.

Comment: *here is my CheckActivity.java (when i receive data, my purpose is that store data to the server. therefore, i don't need to use layout.* don't use an activity then