# Running multiple instances of the same android service

Tags: android, android-service

If I create an android service using `startService()` followed by `bindService()`, and I never call `stopService()`. 
Now, every time my app calls `startService()` and `bindService()`, will it create a new instance of the service or reuse the existing one?

If a new instance is created...is the old instance still running or is it terminated?

Comment: you should not create the service every time.you have to check the service whether it is running or not.then start the service.

Comment: it will reuse same instance of service. and when new instance is created your old instance will be garbage unless your service is not listening to some broadcast or listener.

Comment: see my answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540312/how-to-make-sure-service-is-not-killed/41540930#41540930

Comment: Yes it will resuse the same instance of service..You can also check it from yourself like print any toast...And check that Is toast is appear twice while i am opening the App multiple time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will it create a new instance

No. If you're calling `startService()` even if service already running, it will call `onStartCommand()` with updated `Intent`

Ps,
Service will run in only one process. So there is no such doubt to create another instance

Comment: Just because a `Service` runs in a single process, doesn't mean that the framework will not create multiple instances of it. Android will create multiple instances of other components like `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver`. Actually, there is a bug in older versions of Android that caused the framework to create multiple instances of `Service` in certain cases. In general, the framework doesn't create multiple instances, but it isn't because the `Service` runs in a single process, it is because the framework is designed to handle `Service` as a singleton.

Comment: Noted. So Android framework handle this stuff itself. Thanks @David

Answer (score 0):

It will not create another service, but redeliver your start Intent into onNewIntent() method

Comment: There is no `onNewIntent()` method in a `Service`.

Comment: sorry, onStartCommand(). IntentService has .onHandleIntent() method.